# MongoDB query: how to add all the dates on which the maximum value occurs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a set of data that looks a little like this:

```
{ "_id": 1, "value": { "startTime": ISODate("2017-02-15T11:30:00Z"), "reading": 100 } }
{ "_id": 2, "value": { "startTime": ISODate("2017-02-14T11:30:00Z"), "reading": 50 } }
{ "_id": 3, "value": { "startTime": ISODate("2017-02-13T11:30:00Z"), "reading": 100 } }
```

I want to find all the dates when the maximum reading occurs to create an object that would look like this:

```
"Maximum" : { "max" : 100, "when" : [ ISODate("2017-02-15T11:30:00Z"), ISODate("2017-02-13T11:30:00Z") ]}
```

The group statement I have so far is:

```
"$group": {
  "_id": null,
  "Maximum": { "$max": { "max": "$value.reading", "when": "$value.startTime" } }
}
```

This only records the first time the maximum reading is seen.

How do I make the "when" include an array of all the dates when we have the maximum reading?

I was thinking it would involve a $push but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

mongo shell command,

```
    db.document.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: "$value.reading",
            when: {
                $push: "$value.startTime"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            "_id": -1
        }
    }, {
        $limit: 1
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Maximum: {
                max: "$_id",
                when: "$when"
            }
        }
    }])
```